# Sync multiple Document folders from different sharepoint sites on PC

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, sync, offline-sync

Is there an easier way to sync multiple document folders/library from different Sharepoint sites within my organisation's Sharepoint to my Windows explorer? Currently the only way I can see this can be done is to go to each of those sharepoint sites online and clicking "sync" on each of the documents folder. I was wondering if there might be a converged solution to sync the top level site which then only shows the documents folder from the sharepoint sites I have permission to access?

I'd like this so everyone in my company don't have to spend time syncing every folder individually.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could first follow the document libraries you want to sync, then go to your personal OneDrive webpage, sync document libraries to windows explorer.
[image]